# Apache Wicket 9.1 CSRF enabled, FormTester submits blocked by resource isolation policy

Tags: wicket

I just enabled CSRF into our Wicket 9.1 application by setting the following line in my WicketApplication as the documentation guides:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new ResourceIsolationRequestCycleListener());
```

The protection itself would seem to be working, but it is breaking our UI tests. When submitting forms via FormTester (see example below), I get an exception "The request was blocked by a resource isolation policy".

```
        WicketApplication app = new WicketApplication(someparams);
        WicketTester tester = new WicketTester(app);
        FormTester form = tester.newFormTester("form");
        ...
        form.submit();
```

Do I need to add some configuration to my WicketTester or FormTester? I don't see anything in the Wicket 9.1 documentation related to the Testers and CSRF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add an appropriate request header before submitting or clicking a link in your test so CSRF protection will let pass the mocked request:

```
tester.addRequestHeader(SEC_FETCH_SITE_HEADER, SAME_SITE);
form.submit();
```

The two constant used in the snipped above are static fields from class FetchMetadataResourceIsolationPolicy. I will add a paragraph in the user guide to provide this information.